# Increasing the amount of product in the cart

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having difficulty raising product quantities after adding products to my cart. I will tell you now step by step.

1- I list my products.

2- I am creating the quantity abbreviation function (miktarKisalt)

3- If the products can be weighed, I simplify the fractions.

4- I then create functions that perform increment and decrement operations. (miktarArttir, miktarAzalt)

5-After updating the quantity of items, the cart list is reloaded and new quantities of products are shown

**What I want is this:**

If you press the plus and minus buttons without having to load the cart list and the new number and the current quantity of products are updated

How can I do that?

[image]

```html
            <div class="count-input space-bottom">
                            <a class="incr-btn" (tap)="miktarAzalt(list.ID, list.MIKTAR, list.FIYAT, list.TUTAR, list.TARTILI) ">–</a>
                            <input class="quantity" readonly type="text" [(ngModel)]="MIKTARMODEL[i]" [value]="miktarAtamaFunc((list.TARTILI == 'E' ? miktarKisalt(list.MIKTAR) : list.MIKTAR),i)" name="quantity" />
                            <a class="incr-btn"  (tap)="miktarArttir(list.ID, list.MIKTAR, list.FIYAT, list.TUTAR, list.TARTILI, i)">+</a>
       </div>
```

**MiktarKisalt Function**

```js
MIKTARMODEL : Array<number> = [];

   
miktarAtamaFunc(MIKTAR, INDEX){
 this.MIKTARMODEL[INDEX]= MIKTAR;

}
miktarKisalt(MIKTAR){
        var miktar = Number(MIKTAR);
        return miktar.toFixed(1);
      }
```

**miktarArttir Function**

```js
 miktarArttir(ID, MIKTAR, FIYAT, TUTAR, TARTILI){

      let header = new Headers();
      header.append("Content-Type","application/json");
      header.append("Accept","application/json");
      
      var arttirici=1;
      if(TARTILI == "E"){
        MIKTAR = parseFloat(MIKTAR);
        arttirici = 0.1;
      }

      MIKTAR += arttirici;
     this.MIKTARMODEL[INDEX] += arttirici;
     
     var siparisDetayUpdate = "http://sitename.com/function";
     var siparisDetayVeri = JSON.stringify({
       DETAYID : ID,
       MIKTAR : MIKTAR,
       ACIKLAMA : 0
     });

     this.http.post(siparisDetayUpdate,siparisDetayVeri,header).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
       
         this.sepetListesi(); // RELOAD CART LIST

     }, (error)=>{
       this.miktarArttir(ID, MIKTAR, FIYAT, TUTAR, TARTILI);
     });
    
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem in your code and can you make 1 plnkr file rather than saperate code?

Comment: I would like to update the quantity without having to do list renewal @WasifKhan

Comment: do you know data-binding in Angular? ngModel will be used in your case.

Comment: Are you an example? @WasifKhan

Comment: I have added example in answer, check it out

Comment: @WasifKhan this isn't the method I want

Answer (score 1):

For updating list without loading, use ngModel.

I have made plnkr example for you.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="list">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/t6jEbCFY1ONH27PYQwz1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The way you can achieve this is nesting a **Div tag<*ngIf="flag">**,have a **flag** variable and whenever the **inc or dec button** is pressed **call a function** and change the boolean variable to **TRUE** ,then the value will reflect.

Comment: I do something like this; I keep all returned values ​​in an array.

Comment: MIKTARMODEL : Array<number> = []; after, [(ngModel)]="MIKTARMODEL[i]" [value]="miktarAtamaFunc((list.TARTILI == 'E' ? miktarKisalt(list.MIKTAR) : list.MIKTAR),i)"

Comment: I'm doing this in the increase button: this.MIKTARMODEL[INDEX]++;

Comment: i want you to ensure that u have a alert inside the .ts to check whether the value gets updated or not ?

Comment: It only increases once. Does not increase it a second time

Comment: where you are storing that incremented value ?

Comment: I keep the previous value in place of the increasing value index number

Comment: i think the problem is here only [value]="miktarAtamaFunc((list.TARTILI == 'E' ? miktarKisalt(list.MIKTAR) : list.MIKTAR),i)", y u are calling a function just use the array value.

Comment: There is a condition here. If the product can be weighed, that is, if it is a fruit, it simplifies the disgrace.

Comment: eventhough it has weight u just calculate the value in the funtion and that value must be shown in the input.

Comment: whenever they click you check whether it has weight or not and calculate accordingly.

Comment: Really thank you so much. When I received the data, I inserted them into the loop and sent the quantities to the form like this. And the problem is solved :)